# Kubernetes fail to drain node

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster which has 12 nodes deployed on VMWare CoreOS. When I try to drain the nodes, this error returns:

```
kubectl drain k8s-worker-001.faza.kz
The Node "k8s-worker-001.faza.kz" is invalid: []: Forbidden: node updates may only change labels, taints, or capacity (or configSource, if the DynamicKubeletConfig feature gate is enabled)
```

Comment: please provide the result for below commands kubectl get nodes kubectl top nodes and also try providing the `kubectl describe node <node_name>` output.